# MS Project can't change filname bevor save

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have the following question:

It seems that I cannot change the name of a project file before it is saved. The following code does not work. Does anyone have a better idea? I am using Project 2016

```
DateToday = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")

Set Test = Application.Projects.Add(False, PTP_Template, False) 
Test.Name = DateToday & " SomeMoreTest"
Test.SaveAs
```

I would like to change the file name so that users already have the correct file name in the file save dialog.

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that I cannot change the name of a project file before it is
> saved.

That is correct. The Project [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.name) property is read-only just as it is with Excel, Word, etc.

The way around this would be to create a macro to save the file for the user. So instead of the user going to File: Save As, they would need to run the macro.